# How to remove column during export report in csv?

Tags: jquery, csv

I am using a jquery code to export a report in csv format.Everything working fine but I want to hide a column name column four from CSV.

Here is my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {



        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td,th)'),



            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard

            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents

            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character

            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character



            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format

            colDelim = '","',

            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',



            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string

            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {

                var $row = $(row),

                    $cols = $row.find('td, th');



                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {

                    var $col = $(col),

                        text = $col.text();



                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes



                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);



            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)

                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)

                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',



            // Data URI

            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);



        $(this)

            .attr({

            'download': filename,

                'href': csvData,

                'target': '_blank'

        });

    }



    // This must be a hyperlink

    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {

        // CSV

        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);



        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false

        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink

    });

});
```

I am giving my working js fiddle below :

http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/925/

Any idea?How to remove this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone your table so you don't change the results on the page and then just remove the first td child, you would need to do this for your TH row as well but this works.

```
 $table = $table.clone();
 $table.find("td:nth-child(4)").remove();
$table.find("th:nth-child(4)").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/929/

Edit just saw you said remove the fourth column. Updated.

Comment: your code is working but there is a problem headning column 4 is exporting which should not be in csv file.Any idea how to remove this heading too?

Comment: I updated the code on SO not fiddle. It is because your heading row uses THs not TDs. That code above should work now.

Answer (score 1):

In this section alter the code as follows:

```
return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
    if(j != 3){
        var $col = $(col),
        text = $col.text();
        return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
    }else{
        return "";
    }

}).get().join(tmpColDelim);
```

Run it in the fiddle and click the export button, you will see the 4th column is not included in the csv output.

Comment: @Wolverine glad to hear it worked out for you.  would appreciate you marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$cols.map(function(…))` function so that it leaves out printing column 4.

```
    return $cols.map(function (j, col) { 
        // add this in here since you only want columns 0, 1, and 2
        if(j<3){  
            var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();
            return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
        }
    }).get().join(tmpColDelim);
```

You can also use the same logic to print out only specific columns. For example, the condition,

```
        if(j==0 || j==2){  
            ….
        }
```

will print out only columns 1 and 3.

**Update:** Just realized this is similar to @Nate's answer below. Didn't realized he'd posted an answer while I was busy typing mine up.

Comment: You just reiterated the logic of my answer except you changed != to less than, which he technically didn't ask for.

Comment: Ah, just realized you posted an answer while I was typing mine up! Just edited my answer to reflect that, and upvoted yours too.